# Dealloc of custom cell loaded from NIB is not called

Tags: iphone, uitableview, memory-management

So I have a subclass UITableViewCell named MCProductCell, which is loaded from a NIB. The problem is that when the table is released, the dealloc method of my custom cell is not called even once.

Here is some sample code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"MCProductCellIdentifier";
    MCProductCell *cell = (MCProductCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
   // Boolean value needed to determine if it is a reused cell or not. If it's not reused we have 
   // to start the thread that loads the image. For reused cells, that thread is started at the
   // end of the scrolling
   BOOL recycled = YES;
   if (cell == nil) {
       NSLog(@"cell alloc");
       recycled = NO;
       NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MCProductCell" owner:self options:nil];
       cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
   }
   MCProduct *product = [products objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   cell.product = product;
   cell.cartViewController = self;
   cell.productImage = product.cachedThumbnailImage;
   if (product.cachedThumbnailImage == nil) {
       cell.productImage = [ViewControllerUtils getDefaultImage];
       if (!recycled)
           [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(loadImage:) toTarget:cell withObject:cell.product.imageThumbnailUrl];
   }

   return cell;
```

}

And for some reason, when I first present my UIViewController, that contains the table, the dealloc method of my custom cell is called ONCE. 
The problem is that in the dealloc method I want to remove the cell as an observer, and if it isn't called, then the cell isn't removed as an observer. 
Also the tableview is an outlet.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out, it must be because the retain count of the cell is not going down to 0.
Which means you have another retain.

My  more experienced colleague thinks its because you are using the detachNewThreadSelector, which probably retains the cell.

He suggested you would load the image by using some type of asynchrony image such as
https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView/

Good luck.

Comment: I have commented all the lines where I create a new thread and I have the same issue. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Maybe there is another place where you retain the cell?

Answer (score 0):

How is the 'cell.cartViewController' property defined? If it's retaining your controller object (self), then you probably have a retain cycle in there!

Comment: I am using assign, and the cartViewController dealloc method is called.